# UIView animateWithDuration not running second time

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've tried a lot of different options, and looked through about 15 stack answers and I just can not figure this out.

The code is basically trying to fade out, and then pop back, a view every time a tap happens.  It works fine the first time, but will not work any subsequent times.

```
- (void)handleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    __block HelpScreenController* weakSelf = self;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:10
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^(void) {
                     weakSelf.view.alpha = 0;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     if (finished) {
                         weakSelf.view.alpha = 100.0f;
                         [weakSelf.view.layer removeAllAnimations];
                         [weakSelf.view setNeedsDisplay];
                     }
                 }];

}
```

It runs perfectly the first tap - it smoothly transitions from opaque to fully transparent over a 10 second period.  Second+ tap(s) it wil sit there for 10 seconds, then go transparent for a heart beat then go back to fully opaque again.

How can I get it to animate smoothly every time?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What animation you expect actually? On tap, the view should fade out slowly in a duration of 10 seconds. Once its completely vanished, suddenly you want make it visible. Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`alpha` values are between `0.0f` and `1.0f`. Setting the `alpha` value in the completion block to `1.0f` instead of `100.0f` should fix the problem.

Because values larger than `1.0f` are all completely opaque, you will not see the transition from `100.0f` to `1.0f` (99% of your animation), so the effective duration of the transition from `1.0f` to `0.0f` would just be about 0.1 seconds instead of 10 (not exactly, because of the animation curve, but you get the idea).

Comment: ok, now I feel like an idiot - I guess that is what I get for writing code late at night after a long day - and with an empty office. Switching from 100.0f to 1.0f (which I already knew about). Worked.

Answer (score 3):

You could just use a CABasicAnimation instead. Try out something like this:

```
- (void)handleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{
   CALayer *viewLayer = self.view.layer;
   [viewLayer removeAllAnimations];
   CABasicAnimation *fader = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
   fader.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
   fader.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
   fader.duration = 10;//change the duration and autoreverses option to fit with your look
   fader.autoreverses = YES;
   fader.repeatCount = 0;
   [viewLayer addAnimation:fader forKey:@"fadeAnimation"];
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It will be better if a panel there to approve the down votes. Here people unnecessarily using the privilege it seems :(

Comment: I ttraules - this was what I was going to try this morning - but really the issue was setting the alpha to 100.0f vs 1.0f.  Thanks!  I gave you an up vote :-)